# Quarto revealjs: increase relative font size of code chunks

Tags: css, r, quarto, reveal.js

.In quarto revealjs the font size for code chunks is smaller than that for text. Changing the base font (using `fontsize`) just changes everything proportionally. I would like to be able to adjust the relative font size for code chunks. I assume this involves custom CSS but I'm not sure what to change.

````
---
format:
  revealjs
---

* Here is text

```{r echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```
````

The output looks like this:

[image: revealjs output]

UPDATE: Modifying `font-size` for `code.sourceCode` answers the question I asked. Modifying `font-size` for `code` changes the size of code, output, *and* it also changes the font size for all verbatim elements. Unfortunately it will change too much for many use cases.

Comment: You can increase code and output but not verbatim elements by putting both `code.sourceCode` and `div.cell-output-stdout` into your CSS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Increase the `font-size` for `code.sourceCode` css selector.

````
---
format:
  revealjs
---

* Here is text

```{r echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```


```{css}
code.sourceCode {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* or try font-size: xx-large; */
}
```
````

---

[image: increased code font size]

---

To change the font size of both code chunk code and output, use only the `code` tag as css selector.

````
---
format:
  revealjs
---

* Here is text

```{r echo=TRUE}
str(mtcars)
```


```{css}
code {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* or try font-size: xx-large; */
}
```
````

Comment: Perfect. I now see that the chunk output is relatively small. Do you happen to know the property controlling that? And is there a standard site where can I find this information, e.g. a list of the properties and what they control?

Comment: Do you want both code and output of the same size?

Comment: @RobertMcDonald, you can check the underlying HTML code after opening the slide in any browser and find what classes control what, and change the CSS property of those classes to get what you want.

Comment: Possibly but not necessarily. I'm teaching a course using revealjs, I'm new to it, and I'm trying to figure out what works with the material

Comment: Looking at the html, the immediate line over the output is `<div class="cell-output cell-output-stdout">`. Using either or both of those as a property doesn't do anything.

Comment: Probably your change is getting overwritten. Try with `!important` in the css rule. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Just to close this, I find that if both `code` and `code.sourceCode` are used, the first controls the output and the second controls the controls the chunk font.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald, it is because of [`CSS specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 7):

If you only want to do this for some code, you could define a new CSS class and use it only when you want:

---

````
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
---

## First Slide

```{css echo=FALSE}
.big-code{
  font-size: 200%  
}
```

<div class=big-code>
```{r echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```
</div>

## Next Slide


```{r echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the answer by @shafee: If you want code and output to be bigger but not other verbatim elements enclosed in backtics (e.g., text `verbatim` text), you can use this:

````
```{css}
code.sourceCode div.cell-output-stdout {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

div.cell-output-stdout {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```
````